# Index was outside the bounds of the array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, listbox

I have a text-file(customers.txt) from which I'm trying to extract certain pieces of data from to place in a list-box(lstReportsUnresolved). I'm using commas to split up lines in the text-box and at a certain split, if the text is equal to "No" then the previous split is added to the listbox.

Code:

```
Private Sub btnUnresolved_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUnresolved.Click
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("customers.txt")
            Dim data As String() = line.Split(",")
            If data(18) = "No" Then
                lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(17))

            End If
            If data(20) = "No" Then
                lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(19))

            End If
            If data(22) = "No" Then
                lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(21))

            End If
            If data(24) = "No" Then
                lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(23))
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

It was working fine earlier, but I came back and now try to run it and it stops and highlights the line `If data(18)="No" Then`with the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Semester Two Project.exe" with additional info saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Here is an example of a line from the text file
Mark,Barry,07/04/1996,Redbrook,Sandymount,Dublin,Ireland,094-378231,085-0983623,markbarry96@gmail.com,Basic Cable,VB Fibre Broadband,VB Sports,VB Movies,Chat Chat Phone,VB Anywhere,VB Data,Unavailable Services,Yes,Incorrect Bill,Yes,Poor Tv Reception,No, ,No

Thank you for your help and time

Comment: This happened to me once, the program was working before and the next day it stopped working. The issue was the file data was changed/deleted. make sure this is not the case.

Comment: If data.Length < 25 Then Throw New Exception("Bad customer data")

Comment: You will get that error is any line has less than 18 commas in it. The example line you posted has more than 18 commas, but there must be a line with less. Perhaps there is an empty line at the end of the file. As @HansPassant suggest, you should check the length if the array before trying to access the items in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to `File.ReadLines()`. The method only reads some (or maybe even one) lines at a time, meaning it could have read less (if it's split into lines) than required to make your split return an array of at least 19 elements. You should use `File.ReadAllLines()` instead.

Just replace `File.ReadLines()` with `File.ReadAllLines()`:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("customers.txt")
```

If this is a big file and you don't want to use `File.ReadAllLines()`, you could instead check the end of the array (if the "No" always appears there), instead of having a static index.

**EDIT:**

Actually, either if you use `ReadLines` or `ReadAllLines` you should probably stick with checking from the end:

```
If data(data.Length - 1) = "No" Then
    lstReportsUnresolved.Items.Add(data(data.Length - 2))
End If
```

Comment: So what's wrong with this answer, Mr. Secret Downvoter?